# Randomly generate integers with a distribution that prefers low ones

Tags: python, random

I have an list ordered by some quality function from which I'd like to take elements, preferring the good elements at the beginning of the list.

Currently, my function to generate the random indices looks essentially as follows:

```
def pick():
    p = 0.2
    for i in itertools.count():
        if random.random() < p:
            break
    return i
```

It does a good job, but I wonder:

1. What's the name of the generated random distribution?
2. Is there a built-in function in Python for that distribution?

Comment: Here is a good article that might help. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python

Comment: You're creating a [`geometric distribution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simulate it via exponential, but this is like making square peg fit round hole. As Mark said, it is geometric distribution - discrete, shifted by 1. And it is right here in the numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = 0.2

def pick():
    for i in itertools.count():
        if random.random() < p:
            break
    return i

q = np.random.geometric(p, size = 100000) - 1
z = [pick() for i in range(100000)]

bins = np.linspace(-0.5, 30.5, 32)

plt.hist(q, bins, alpha=0.2, label='geom')
plt.hist(z, bins, alpha=0.2, label='pick')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think that's the only fully correct answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing sounds a lot like the exponential distribution.  It already exists in the `random` module.

Here is some code that takes just the integer part of sampling from an exponential distribution with a rate parameter of 100.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = [int(random.expovariate(1/100)) for i in range(10000)]
h,b = np.histogram(d, bins=np.arange(0,max(d)))

plt.bar(left=b[:-1], height=h, ec='none', width=1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What the OP describes is a geometric distribution rather than an exponential, but taking the floor of an exponentially-distributed r.v. does indeed give a geometric distribution.

Comment: @MarkDickinson a geometric distribution shifted by 1

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Depends on your definitions. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricDistribution.html, for example.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Ah, I see from your answer (+1) that NumPy and SciPy do use the "supported on 1, 2, 3, ..." definition. That's unfortunate, in Python world. :-(

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes, quite unfortunate, indeed - was burned by it once

Answer (score 1):

`random.random()` defaults to a uniform distribution, but there are other methods within `random` that would also work. For your given use case, I would suggest `random.expovariate(2)` ([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.expovariate), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)). This is an exponential distribution that will heavily prefer lower values. If you google some of the other methods listed in the documentation, you can find some other built-in distributions.

Edit: Be sure to play around with the argument value for `expovariate`. Also note that it doesn't guarantee a value less than 1, so you might need to ensure that you only use values less than 1.